# TinyMCE Pass Content from Dialog Popup to Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I've been working on an issue for a while, and can't seem to find a solution. I'm trying to pass content from the dialog window to the editor. What I am looking to do is when the user clicks on my custom button on the editor, a dialog window opens (got that). Then, the window opens an external page which displays a table (got that). Then, the user is to click on radio button, and depending on which row they checked, certain attributes are passed (this is what I can't get).

Here is my code for what I have, so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#postContent',
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false,
        plugins: 'code, hr, image, link, media, paste, table, textcolor',
        toolbar: 'undo redo pastetext | formatselect | bold italic underline | subscript superscript | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | filelibrary link unlink | hr table | code',
        setup: function(e) {
            e.addButton('filelibrary', {
                image: 'file-library.svg',
                title: 'File Library',
                onclick: function() {
                    e.windowManager.open({
                        title: 'File Library',
                        url: 'file-library.php',
                        width: $(window).width() * .75,
                        height: $(window).height() * .75,
                        buttons: [{
                            text: 'Insert to Post',
                            onclick: function(e) {
                                var d = $('.option:checked').attr('data');
                                tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<p>' + d + '</p>');
                                top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
                            }
                        }, {
                            text: 'Cancel',
                            onclick: 'close'
                        }]
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Just wanna get pointed in the right direction. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINALLY! Took me a while, but I solved my own issue. I'm posting my solution for anyone that has come, or will come, across this issue.

In my `file-library.php`, I needed to add:

```
$('.option').click(function() {
     parent.tinymce.activeEditor.d = $('.option:checked').attr('data');
});
```

And, in this is what was needed within the main `onclick` function:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<p>' + tinymce.activeEditor.d + '</p>');
top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
```

Whew! What a relief...

Answer (score 0):

It works for me but replacing:

```
parent.tinymce.activeEditor.d = $('.option:checked').attr('data');
```

for:

```
parent.tinymce.activeEditor.d = $('.option:checked').attr('value');
```

What a relief too!